# How to download an in-memory object as a JSON file to the client from server side Blazor?

Tags: c#, .net, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a class containing some info a user might want to download after visiting a page. Some initial digging points towards using the JSRuntime interop.

MyClass.cs

```
public class MyClass
    {
        public int Count { get; set; }
        public string Summary { get; set; }
    }
```

MyClassPage.razor

```
<button type="button" class="ml-auto p-2 btn btn-primary" onclick="@DownloadFile">Download</button>

...

async Task DownloadFile()
    {
        var testObj = new SpeciesData();
        testObj.Count = 100;
        testObj.Summary = "Lorem Ipsum";

        var fileName = "testing.json";

        var serializedObject = JsonSerializer.Serialize(testObj);
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializedObject);

        await JS.InvokeAsync<object>(
            "saveAsFile",
            fileName,
            Convert.ToBase64String(bytes ));

    }
```

How do I get the file to download? Not sure where/how I inject the JS file to the proj (with a function named saveAsFile I assume?)

Similar questions I've referenced:

- [How to download a file from blazor server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57327440/how-to-download-a-file-from-blazor-server-side)
- [Download multiple files (50mb) blazor server-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68126717/download-multiple-files-50mb-blazor-server-side)
- [Server side download in blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63945295/server-side-download-in-blazor)
- [Create and download JSON file in Blazor Server Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64464259/create-and-download-json-file-in-blazor-server-application)

Comment: Possible solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53822526/251674